# Get the value of a JSON array with _attribute

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a strange looking JSON file (I think?) generated from elasticsearch.

I was wondering if anyone know how I could retrieve the data from a JSON object looking like this:

```
u'hits : {
        u'hits : [{
                u'_score' : 2.1224,
                u'_source' : {u'content': u'SomethingSomething' }
                  }],
        u'total: 8 }
u'took: 2 }
```

I can retrieve the total by writing {{ results.hits.hits.total }}, however, the underscore symbol (_) in front of the attribute name "_score" makes it impossible to retrieve the value of that attribute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: results.hits.hits is an array, do you consider it ? how do you try to retrieve the _score field ?

Comment: {% for results in res %} and then {{ results.hits.hits.score. But this returns nothing. If i try results.hits.hits._score, i get a TemplateSyntaxError. @Sylwit

Comment: you don't get the 1st item of your array. See @mQuixaba response below `{{ results.hits.hits[0]._score }}` The [0] is what you forget

Comment: Sadly that didn't work either, still complaining about a TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]._score'. But results.hits.hits[0]._score is a valid syntax @Sylwit?

Comment: @Sylwit + 1 for you two good sir's. Have I provided a bit more information this would probably be quit a easy fix. Im writing in Python and the correct way (it seems) to access the first object in a array is .0 not [0]. Thanks for the comments, which led me to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{ results.hits.hits[0]._score }}
{{ results.hits.hits[0]._source }}
```